# MySQL: Buscar erros usando WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, validação

Tenho a seguinte situação com as tabelas abaixo. Preciso fazer algumas verificações em "seriais" (se o serial existe, se é válido, etc, e outras validações junto a outras tabelas) a partir de diversos seriais (até milhares por vez) e, caso não seja válido, registrar em "seriais_erros" o ID do serial (se ele estiver cadastrado) ou o serial em si, caso não esteja cadastrado e não seja válido.

Qual a forma mais adequada de resolver isso, uma vez que preciso tratar cada serial separadamente? Como se trata de milhares de seriais a cada vez, me preocupo muito com relação à performance.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `seriais` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `serial_erros` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serial_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `erro` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `serial_id` (`serial_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Existem índices para esta tabela ? Quais ? Estude também o uso do EXISTS

Comment: Bom existem varias maneiras de preparar Neston, mas no seu caso, já pensou em criar uma View que vincule as 2 tabelas, iria lhe dar um resultado bem mais rápido em pesquisas.

Comment: No caso é recomendável que se defina o campo `serial` como índice da tabela, para buscas de larga escala. O que pretendes dizer exatamente com `usando o WHERE IN` ? O que vejo aí é uma consulta _SQL_ normal usando apenas _SQL_. Num contexto geral, com o que está realmente relacionada a dúvida ?